# How to write i-circumflex

Tags: accents

In some French words when the circumflex is used over the i, there is no dot on the i.  When I try to do it as described in "A Guide to Latex" the dot appears and the circumflex is too high.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Use `\"\i` as here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of code? What does the guide you mention say?

Comment: @PaulGessler - Did you mean to write `\^i`?

Comment: Make sure you are using the `T1` encoding by issuing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. This will ensure that you get the pre-composed glyph (provided it is available in the font) and not simply a circumflex on top of a regular 'i'.

Comment: @Mico, whoops, yes, I meant `\^\i` not `\"\i`. But now (in testing your comment) I see that dotless i (`\i`) is not required. So there must be more going on here if the dot appears, as W D says.

Comment: I only observed this in math mode, with `\hat{i}`; otherwise, whatever be the input or the font encodings, I obtain a quite normal `î`. In math mode, you have to code a `\dotless i`: `\hat{i}` and `\hat{\i}` _are_ different.

Comment: @Bernard It depends on whether `dotlessi` is in the font, though. It should be for anything vaguely standard, however. The reason to use `T1` is twofold. First, copy-and-paste will fail for many characters in `OT1` but not `T1`. Second, even for those not in `T1`, accent placement is improved (at least for lowercase).

Comment: We really need an MWE to say anything useful here. Presumably the OP is not using Computer Modern else the problem wouldn't occur in this form. Or if the OP is using it, something else is configured oddly. Either way, without the code we can only guess.

Comment: @cfr: I know that – personally, I always use T1 fonts (or opentype with XeLaTeX). My comment was just to show there normally is no problem whatsoever, except possibly in maths.

Comment: @Bernard I figured you knew. I was actually mostly thinking of the OP's comment about the height of the accent when I first wrote that. In some cases, composted characters get the accent heights wrong although pre-composed ones do not. (Latin Modern seems to have improved in this respect but used to demonstrate this issue. Pre-composed glyphs had accents right but something in the font specification caused combining accents to be placed too high in some cases.) However, as you say, the issue here must be more basic since none of that should use 'i' rather than 'dotlessi' regardless.

Answer (score 6):

Just to demonstrate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mytest}{%
  \^{a} \^{e} \^{i} \^{o} \^{u} \^{w} \^{y}\par
  \textit{\^{a} \^{e} \^{i} \^{o} \^{u} \^{w} \^{y}}\par
  \textsc{\^{a} \^{e} \^{i} \^{o} \^{u} \^{w} \^{y}}\par
  \^{A} \^{E} \^{I} \^{O} \^{U} \^{W} \^{Y}\par
  $\hat{i} \hat{\imath}$}

\begin{document}

\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont

\verb|OT1|:

\mytest

\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont

\verb|T1|:

\mytest

\end{document}
```

will produce:

[image: Circumflex accents everywhere...]

Note that using `T1` not only improves the placement of the accent, it also supports copy-and-paste for the first five characters. To see this, try copy-and-pasting the generated text. You will find that only the first five characters in the lines using `T1` paste correctly. The others will decompose into separate circumflexs and letters.

This does not work for the final two characters, ŵ and ŷ, because these are not included in the `T1` encoding. However, even in these cases, the accent placement is improved.

To actually use `T1` in your documents, you should use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

rather than the above code. I didn't do that because I wanted to demonstrate both `OT1` and `T1` in a single document.

As LaRiFaRi and Sean Allred point out, using

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

*or* switching to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX lets you input the accented characters directly. (I use the `inputenc` option but they all work.)

```
â ê î ô û ŵ ŷ
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried some of this? It's more a comment and I will delete it, when you show an MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % to insert the character directly by copy paste or as ^+i typed on your keyboard
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % to lower the accent

\begin{document}
î % direct with utf8
 \^i % LaTeX command
\end{document}
```

Make sure, to save your .tex-file encoded as utf8.

[image]

**Edit:** As Sean mentioned below in comment, the possibility exists, to use TeX-engines which support utf8 directly. If you are interested (and it's the way I do it), it would look like this:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatextra}

\begin{document}
î % direct with utf8
 \^i % LaTeX command
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note with the Unicode option: more modern engines (notably `xetex` and `luatex`, called as `xelatex` and `lualatex`, respectively) don't need the `inputenc` or `fontenc` packages and can work with Unicode directly.